# Insert query in yii2.0 framework

Tags: yii2-basic-app

I am using Yii 2.0 framework , Can anyone help me to write insert query in the controller please, I am writing query like this, is this a proper query

```
$userId = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    $restId = \app\models\Restaurantbusiness::find()->select('restaurentID')->where(['userId' => $userId ])->one(); 
    $restdetailId = $restId->restaurentID;
    $restomenuID = Restomenu::find()->insert('restaurantBusiness_restaurentID')->where(['restaurantBusiness_restaurentID' => $restdetailId])->One();
```

please help me to write the correct insert query. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ok i assume no one knows :-/

i found the solution

there is no need to write any insert query at all,
in controller before saving 
i wrote this

$model->restaurantBusiness_restaurentID= $restdetailId;

thats all.